# Flow to change promoted state of a page after certain time. No errors but not working

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow, power-automate

So with help I have this flow that supposed to change promoted state of a page after the page is one day old and has F7 in the file name from 2 to 0. There is no errors and flow runs fine, finds the pages and condition works but after that, nothing. After the flow is done pages still have promoted state 2. Any ideas?
[image][image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using PnP Powershell, seeing **PromotedState** is a Read Only Field (ReadOnlyField =True)

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -SPOManagementShell

Get-PnPField -List "SitePages"

$fld=Get-PnPField -List "SitePages" -Identity f5ad16a2-85be-46b2-b5f0-2bb8b4a5074a
$fld.ReadOnlyField
```

You may need to update it to read/write first and try again

```
set-pnpfield -Identity "Promoted State" -List "Site Pages" -Values @{ReadOnlyField=$false}
```

For additional info, visit this [this link](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/issue-when-updating-new-page-promoted-state-in-microsoft-flow/td-p/252582)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately SharePoint does not support "un-promoting" news. You might be able to modify the PromotedState field by using the other answer here and get the immediate result you're looking for, but it will have undesirable side effects and leave your library in an unsupported state.

For example, the FirstPublishedDate of all news published in a library where the PromotedState field has been modified will just be January 1st. There is no good way to fix this once you've done it, unfortunately. I've had some success with deleting the PromotedState field (it came back automatically after I tried creating a new page) but that is a destructive action as well and will result in losing that field's data for your existing pages.